# What is the cause of "S-shaped" Raman spectra?

Tags: spectroscopy, raman-spectroscopy

I'm doing Raman on graphite and graphite flouride (GF) obtained from suppliers for comparison with material I'm working on. For graphite, I get spectra which is consistent with literature data.

However when it comes to the GF, I get this "S-curve"-like spectra (as in the sketch below) with no discernable peaks instead of the less defined but still visible peaks in the 1200-1800 cm-1 region (even with a more "focused" scan) as in [Gupta et al. 2003](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022113902003238) [image: Sketch of obtained GF spectrum]

I take these spectra in the same sessions as the graphite, on the same Raman microscope and I calibrate to a Si reference at the start of every session, both using the same 532 nm laser source (consistent with literature).

I would like to know what causes this (and how to resolve it). Any recommendations for guides, textbooks or other literature on such Raman "weirdness" would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: That just indicates substantial disorder.

Comment: Is the horizontal axis of your plot linear or logarithmic? How long and at what temperature were your samples fluorinated?  Might your results be consistent with the bottom data curves (L-7, H-4, H-5) in Figures 4 and 5 of Gupta's paper where the peaks disappear due (as @Jon-Custer notes) to high disorder in the samples.

Comment: Thank you both. @DavidBailey the Horizontal axis is linear. The sample is commercial stock from Merck (Sigma-Aldrich) and unfortunately they don't provide the synthesis process, though comparing to the colour and stoichiometry on the label it probably matches H-5/H-6 the closest. I am looking to compare it to the samples I will be synthesising.